# Acronyms with description environment

Tags: acronyms, description

I have an editorial template to write a book's chapter. The publisher wants the authors to use the description environment to display acronyms. However, due to `acronym`'s package facilities I am trying to use it also. The MWE is below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nolist,printonlyused]{acronym}

\begin{document

\let\olditem\item

\makeatletter
\ifAC@printonlyused
    \renewcommand{\item}[2]{%
        \expandafter\ifx\csname acused@#1\endcsname\AC@used
            \acrodef{#1}{#2}
            \olditem[#1]{#2}
        \else
            \olditem[]{}\vspace{-\baselineskip}
        \fi}
\else
    \renewcommand{\item}[2]{%
        \acrodef{#1}{#2}
        \olditem[#1]{#2}}
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{description}
    \item{3GPP}{Third Generation Partnership Project}
    \item{D2D}{Device-to-Device}
    \item{M2M}{Machine-to-Machine}
\end{description}

\let\item\olditem

%\ac{3GPP}
\ac{D2D}
\ac{M2M}

\end{document}
```

The problem is when a certain acronym isn't used, because it leaves an empty line. I tried to remove the empty line with `\olditem[]{}\vspace{-\baselineskip}` but it is ugly. Is there a better way to achieve the same result?

Comment: »The publisher wants the authors to use the description environment to display acronyms« - you mean you _must_ use an explicit `{description}` environment? Or may the list of acronyms use it implicitly (maybe hidden in some `\printacronyms` command? The latter would make much more sense, IMHO.

Comment: The author has defined some kind of enhanced description environment that calculates the widest element in the list. Therefore, he wants the authors to use that environment.

Comment: Still: may it be implicit? Additional question: does it follow the standard syntax, i.e `\begin{description} \item[foo] bar \end{description}`?

Comment: Yes it follows the standard sintax, just like the way it is in the MWE. The enhanced description environment is nothing more than `\begin{description}[BLABLA]`, where BLABLA is the widest element in the list. Moreover, I think I can use it implicit, however, I would prefer to use it explicitly.

Comment: Well, the default list that `acronym` uses _is_ a `description` environment and its wrapper `\begin{acronym}` has exactly the same »enhancement«: an optional argument for the widest item so you are trying to reinvent the wheel, kind of...

Comment: I know what you mean. The problem is that I want to use the description environment of the publisher (it may have other ``enhancements'' that I didn't investigate) and therefore keep the chapter consistent with other chapters (I am just author of a chapter).

Comment: BTW: you could simply skip the else branch containing `\olditem[]{}\vspace{-\baselineskip}` entirely if you don't want any output there